what should I use only MUI components or mix html tags with mui components
Is it a ok if I used some html tags with MUI components or I should stick only with MUI comp in my page, what's the best choice for performance
also is there any other library that is better than MUI in terms of performance and simplicity of coding

✅ You can use a combination of both.
I follow this rule: If I have to add some styling or require some MUI-specific feature or prop I use an MUI component. Otherwise, I use HTML tag.
There are PROS and CONS of both cases. You can check this documentation: When to use MUI system?
And yes, it impacts performance. Check the screenshot below: 
So I give you the cases where I prefer the MUI component over HTML or vice versa:

Using HTML tag over MUI component:
You often just want to wrap your child components or tags with a div.
Use this: <div> { child } </div>
Over this: <Box component="div"> { child } </Box>

Using MUI component over HTML tag:
Usually, when you add an image you require some styling around it. You can use MUI sx prop to style and adjust an img.
Use this: Box component="img" src="..." sx={{ ... }}/>
Over this: <img src="..." style={{ ... }}/> 


